# When I search the discard pile, which direction do I search

Tags: eldritch-horror

The reference guide says, under Gaining Posessions and Condition, that when gaining a card with a specific trait:

> The investigator searches that card type's deck then discard pile for the first card matching the specified trait and gains that card.

If I cannot find the card in the deck, do I search the discard pile from the most recently discarded card first, or the least recently discarded card?
Usually discard piles are face-up so that the most recently discarded is on top of the pile.

Now, searching is specified as looking through the deck from the bottom up.
Is the bottom of the discard deck the most recently discarded card then or the first one that was discarded?

My inclination is to think that the bottom of the deck is the side that displays the contents of the card, as searching through the details of the cards tends to be easier parsing through the cards from that direction, and this search was likely described to be bottom-up to make it easier to execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An official answer from Nikki Valens (head designer of Eldritch Horror):

> The investigator will search the discard pile bottom to top. That is, starting with cards that were discarded earliest and ending with the cards discarded most recently.